# Date format exception for Fri Aug 31 00:00:00 CAT 2012

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I was trying to format the date `Fri Aug 31 00:00:00 CAT 2012` using the format `EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy` but am getting `Unparseable date: "Fri Aug 31 00:00:00 CAT 2012"`

Am using this code

```
String DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy"; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT); 
Date date = sdf.parse(myObj.getDate().toString());
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You don't get an `unparseable date` exception if you are trying to format a date. Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AndyTurner pls check  my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `yyyy` in your format.
Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse("Fri Aug 31 00:00:00 CAT 2012");
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got the year token in there twice:

```
String DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy"; 
                                 ^ remove this one.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that you already have a `Date`-object, want to format it using its standard output via `toString()` and parse it again to a `Date`-object. This procedure even looses the millisecond fraction of the original `Date`-object (by `myObj.getDate()`). Anyway, the right format pattern to do parsing is:

> EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy

And don't forget to set the locale of your `SimpleDateFormat`-object to English. Note that you had the yyyy-part two times and also used "h" (hour of am/pm) instead of "H" (hour of day). See also the source code of class `java.util.Date`:

```
/**
 * Converts this <code>Date</code> object to a <code>String</code>
 * of the form:
 * <blockquote><pre>
 * dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy</pre></blockquote>
 * where:<ul>
 * <li><tt>dow</tt> is the day of the week (<tt>Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed,
 *     Thu, Fri, Sat</tt>).
 * <li><tt>mon</tt> is the month (<tt>Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun,
 *     Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec</tt>).
 * <li><tt>dd</tt> is the day of the month (<tt>01</tt> through
 *     <tt>31</tt>), as two decimal digits.
 * <li><tt>hh</tt> is the hour of the day (<tt>00</tt> through
 *     <tt>23</tt>), as two decimal digits.
 * <li><tt>mm</tt> is the minute within the hour (<tt>00</tt> through
 *     <tt>59</tt>), as two decimal digits.
 * <li><tt>ss</tt> is the second within the minute (<tt>00</tt> through
 *     <tt>61</tt>, as two decimal digits.
 * <li><tt>zzz</tt> is the time zone (and may reflect daylight saving
 *     time). Standard time zone abbreviations include those
 *     recognized by the method <tt>parse</tt>. If time zone
 *     information is not available, then <tt>zzz</tt> is empty -
 *     that is, it consists of no characters at all.
 * <li><tt>yyyy</tt> is the year, as four decimal digits.
 * </ul>
 *
 * @return  a string representation of this date.
 * @see     java.util.Date#toLocaleString()
 * @see     java.util.Date#toGMTString()
 */
public String toString() {
    // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
```